# Adding mean and std to jointplot margins

Tags: python, plot, statistics, seaborn, jointplot

I have a seaborn.jointplot very similar to the figure I've attached (from the seaborn gallery). However, I wonder if it is possible to add e.g. a colored line to each of the marginal plots to mark the mean and a range marking for the interval of one standard deviation around it. I like the overall design of the seaplot figures but I kinda need that extra piece of information.

[image: Seaborn Jointplot]

Code from the gallery which generated the appended plot:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_theme(style="darkgrid")

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.jointplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips,
                  kind="reg", truncate=False,
                  xlim=(0, 60), ylim=(0, 12),
                  color="m", height=7)
```

What I produced using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56116021/add-arbitrary-lines-on-seaborn-jointplot):

[image: First own try]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw lines on the joint and marginal axes, as shown for example in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56116021/add-arbitrary-lines-on-seaborn-jointplot).

Here is an example approach to show the mean and the standard deviation.  Many alternatives are possible.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_theme(style="darkgrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.jointplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips,
                  kind="reg", truncate=False,
                  xlim=(0, 60), ylim=(0, 12),
                  color="m", height=7)

x_mean = tips["total_bill"].mean()
x_std = tips["total_bill"].std()
g.ax_marg_x.axvspan(x_mean - x_std, x_mean + x_std, color='red', alpha=0.1)

y_mean = tips["tip"].mean()
y_std = tips["tip"].std()
g.ax_marg_y.axhspan(y_mean - y_std, y_mean + y_std, color='red', alpha=0.1)

g.refline(x=x_mean, y=y_mean, color='red', ls='--')

plt.show()
```

[image: sns.jointplot with mean and sdev]

PS: As mentioned in the comments [`refline()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.JointGrid.refline.html) can be used to replace these four lines:

```py
for ax in [g.ax_joint, g.ax_marg_x]:
    ax.axvline(x_mean, color='red', ls='--')
for ax in [g.ax_joint, g.ax_marg_y]:
    ax.axhline(y_mean, color='red', ls='--')
```